# What are the issues with pulling power off a single battery while it is wired in series with a second battery?

Tags: batteries

I have a pair of 18v RYOBI batteries that are removable and recharged separately in a standard charger.

I have a pair of small motors that require 18volts, and a pair of small motors that require 36 volts. I have wired the two 18v batteries in series and tested running both sets of motors, the 18volt motors pulling power from the first battery, and the 36 volt motors pulling power from across both batteries. Initial testing has been successful.

What are the issues that I should understand about this arrangement and is there any way to mitigate these issues? Thanks.

Comment: You can overcharge the upper battery and undercharge the lower battery doing that. It can be somewhat acceptable with lead-acid batteries but not at all with lithium-ion.

Comment: I am not sure I understand this. Charging does not occur in this system. The batteries are removed and plugged individually into their own chargers. I was thinking that the batteries would try to balance but I don't see how undercharging or overcharging would occur. Also, the Ryobi batteries have circuitry that disconnects them when they reach a lower charge limit so that they will not be damaged by being discharged.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are better off getting a dc to dc converter to convert the 36V to 18V to run the 18V motors.

This is because you will cause an imbalance between the two batteries by using only one to run the 2 18V motors.

You could, possibly, consider running 1 18V motor on each battery but that may mean control and wiring issues and the possibility someone makes a wrong connection... **Lots** of sparks or a fire then.

Comment: The batteries may drain at different rates, but I thought they would balance each other with charge from the higher flowing to the lower. I can add a converter, but cost is quite high for one that can handle the amperage which is on a par with the power tools that these batteries are typically used in. The option I am considering is to simply add a third battery and separate the two circuits. I would like to avoid this if possible due to weight and space constraints.

Comment: How do you think charge will pass through one battery to the other without affecting it? It is not like thoughts between ears.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that, when you connect two batteries in series, maximal current output drops, because internal resistance of batteries adds up.

Comment: The max. output current is determined by the weaker battery. If both are the same, the max. current will not  decrease. You may have two battery resistances, but also double the voltage and double the dissipation capacity.

Comment: My understanding is that all of these Lithium Ion battery packs are made up of individual ~3.7v cells that are wired in series with 5 cells to an 18v battery pack. When you then take two 18volt packs and wire them in series, you effectively get the same thing as a 10 cell or 36volt pack. Resistance shouldn't be any different between a single 10 cell pack and two 5 cell packs wired in series. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, you are right. However 10cells will have twice resistance in comparison with 5cells only (if connected in series). Also in your configuration one battery will discharge quickier and resistance of both will increase also due to that. You can use a DC-DC converter if current output is not sufficient.